# Помогите дописать сочинение

Tags: егэ

(1)Недавно в статье видного лингвиста Н
(1)Недавно в статье видного лингвиста Н. Вашкевича я обнаружил предельно ясное и точное определение термина «информация». ^Оказывается, он происходит не от латинского «знания», как принято считать, а от арабского «различие»! (3)И сразу вспомнился мне эпизод полувековой давности...

(4)Я заканчивал десятилетку весной 1953 года, как раз тогда, когда умер Сталин. (5)Его преемник Г.М. Маленков выступил на каком-то важном собрании с программной речью, в которой в числе прочего была дана важная для всей партийной идеологической работы установка — определение «типического». (6)Эта 
формулировка, сразу же провозглашённая «классической», гласила: «Типическое не то, что массово, а то, что с наибольшей полнотой выражает сущность данной социальной силы». (7)Всех старшеклассников тогда задолбали «классическим определением типического по Маленкову», мы, конечно, знали его назубок.

(8)А в нашем классе перед самым окончанием школы случился род загадочного поветрия, возникшего в связи со странной особенностью нашего учителя физики. (9)3адавая уроки на дом, он всегда почему-то произносил фразу: «Задачки будут разные: одна на сообразительность и две на подстановочку»... (10)Это слово «разные» подхватил кто-то из наших ребят, который стал каждый раз переспрашивать: «Евгений Евгеньевич! А задачки-то будут разные?». (11)«Разные», — простодушно подтверждал Евгений Евгеньевич и недоумевал, почему при этих словах весь класс покатывается со смеху. (12)Потом и другие учителя столкнулись с загадочным феноменом: 10 «Б» начинает хохотать, как только услышит на уроке слово «разное». (13)На какое-то время это слово стало своеобразным паролем класса, его тайной, в которую не был посвящён никто, кроме нас.

(14)На экзамене по литературе мы сидели на задней парте с Юрой Карпухиным, ожидая своей очереди тянуть билеты. (15)Юра был плотный, молчаливый, физически очень крепкий парень с задумчивым взглядом и изредка пробегавшей по лицу глумливой ухмылкой.

(16) Учился средне, в спорах и разговорах не участвовал, но считался анархистом на том основании, что на обложке его табеля аккуратным почерком были выведены три фразы: «Анархия — мать порядка», «Анархия — нет слаще слова, нет чище мысли» и почему-то «Лапа класса лежит на хищнике — Лубянская 
лапа ЧеКа»...

(17)Слушая, как экзаменационная комиссия допекает наших однокашников «классическим определением типического по Маленкову», Карпухин, вдруг наклонившись ко мне, сдерживаемым баском спросил меня:

(18)— А мог бы ты, Гера, дать классическое определение разного?

(19)Я, конечно, не мог. (20)И тут Юра произнёс чеканную фразу:

(21)— Разное — это то, что с наибольшей полнотой характеризует данный объект!

(22)Меня тогда поразила эта запомнившаяся мне на всю жизнь формулировка. (23)Я всегда чувствовал в ней какую-то не осознаваемую мной глубину! (24)И только сейчас, читая Вашкевича, я понял: в 1953 году десятиклассник Юрий Карпухин дал классическое определение ничему другому, как информации — различий, наиболее полно характеризующих данный объект!

(25)Я не знаю, в какой институт поступил Карпухин и кем по специальности он стал. (26)Я не знаю, где он сейчас. (27)Но я до сих пор не перестаю дивиться необыкновенным способностям Юрия и многих других моих одноклассников — выпускников обычного класса обычной московской средней школы.

Вот,что я написала,добавьте ещё что-нибудь
Школьникам приходится иметь дело с разными определениями:с обычными толкованиями слов. Но кто-то пытается запомнить и растолковать слово по словарю,а кто-то применяет и опыт из собственной жизни.Смог ли обычный ученик московской школы понять определение слова "информация" и так его хорошо запомнить? Нет,конечно,если бы не помощь Юрия Кормухина,молчаливого парня с задумчивым взглядом. Оказывается всё гениальное - просто.

Answer (score 1):

Виктория, во-первых, у Вас фактическая ошибка: не Кормухина, а Карпухина. Во-вторых,проблема мелковата. Проблема - вопрос, который интересует не одного человека, а многих. Можно её сформулировать так: проблема отношения к формулировкам.Можно задать вопрос: какие формулировки мы называем классическими?Или: Только ли классики создают классические формулировки?

Мы часто сталкиваемся в жизни с формулировками, определениями, особенно в науке. Автор вспоминает события 50-х годов, когда старшеклассников заставляли заучивать определения терминов партийных идеологов, как их "задолбали классическим определением типического по Маленкову» и они иронизировали, давая всему определения, перефразируя формулировку. Но одно определение,данное его одноклассником Юрием Карпухиным,запомнилось ему глубиной мысли, оно оказалось действительно классическим определением термина "информация".Автор вспоминает его уже будучи взрослым, когда обнаружил предельно ясное и точное определение термина «информация» у Вашкевича.

Позиция автора ясна: "классические"формулировки не те, которые даются классиками (идеологии или науки), а те, глубина и верность которых проверяется временем.
Например, классическое определение счастья:"Счастье - это соответствие личных наклонностей потребностям других людей". А вот мне близка фраза героини фильма Станислава Ростоцкого «Доживём до понедельника»: «Счастье – это когда тебя понимают». Вот она больше подходит под классическое определение.Или возьмём классическое определение правды в словаре Ожегова - ПРАВДА -то, что существует в действительности, соответствует реальному положению вещей. Но почему же при произнесении этого слова мы сразу вспоминаем Сатина из "На дне"Горького и его "Человек - вот правда"? Вот оно стало классикой.

Таким образом, автор прав,классические определения часто действительно создаются не классиками, а простыми людьми, умеющими глубоко мыслить.